# EF/Linq - Sort collection before grouping

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a one-to-many relationship between a project table and an audit table. I'm trying to pick out from the audit table the latest entry for each project entity.

From what I understand to do this I should be able to sort my audit collection by date before grouping by project id, so that I can select the first entry for each group (project id) to get the latest entry.

But when I run my ef/linq query, the results are not correct and the order-by seems to be ignored - even the generated sql doesn't include the order by statement.

Heres the simple example I've tried.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    var audit = from a in ctx.ProjectAudits
                orderby a.CreatedDate descending
                group a by a.ProjectId into grp
                select grp.FirstOrDefault();

    var resultsList = audit.ToList();
}
```

The results always return with the earliest audit entry for each project id and not the latest.

Is there something wrong with this query; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: ordering effects the results, not tables you are joining to.

Comment: @Jodrell ok so how do I ensure that when I get the first entry for each group that the first one is the latest?

Comment: You can't really do that in a single statement in T-SQL - grouping by project ID will give you a single row for each project ID with aggregated values for the other columns - you need to subquery to get the first item for each, not sure how that translates into EF or Linq...

Comment: @Charleh that's the problem I've faced - I can write the sql (actually without a group by) using sub query but translating the ef in the bit that doesn't work for me - I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4014958/81053 and which initially does a group by and then uses that to power another query ie select entity and just 1 of it joined entities - I've taken this and added the order by - but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Okay, how about this?

```
ctx.ProjectAudits
    .GroupBy(p => p.ProjectId)
    .Select(p => p.OrderByDescending(j => j.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

Don't have VS with me here, but it should theoretically group your records, order them within the group by their creation date, and select the first record from each group.

Comment: "the latest entry for each project entity". Your query select entry for one project only.

Comment: @HoberMellow that's right for all projects i want to list the latest audit entity not just one project

Comment: @Trickery Top job! This did the trick and when I read it through makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you need to look at a different approach. Instead of ordering, why don't you group and then select the audit with the maximum `CreatedDate`.  I've not tested the following and am just throwing it out there:

```
var audit = from a in ctx.ProjectAudits
            group a by a.ProjectId into grp
            select new {
              // whatever your other properties are
              CreatedDate = grp.Max(i => i.CreatedDate)
            };
```

Or, as most people prefer the method syntax:

```
var audit = ctx.ProjectAudits
               .Where(i => i.CreatedDate == ctx.ProjectAudits
                                               .Max(x => x.CreatedDate));
```

**EDIT** - made some changes, and tested with a test class and a `List<TestClass>` and the above works with that.

Comment: @HoberMellow Yep that too, nice one.