# LINQ Join to Top(1)

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am again struggling with syntax for a LINQ query.

I looked at [LINQ Join on top 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014855/linq-join-on-top-1) but I'm still pretty confused!

A User can have 0-n Photos.

I have the SQL I need but cannot work out how to implement this in LINQ. The SQL is this:

```
SELECT   User.Name, Photo.ImageUri
FROM     User
LEFT OUTER JOIN     Photo
ON       Photo.Id =
         (
         SELECT  TOP 1 Id 
         FROM    Photo
         WHERE   UserId = User.Id
         )
```

I am using Entity Framework (.NET Core) and have tried the following:

```
        var users = _context.Users.Select(x => new
        {
            name= x.Name,
            photo = x.Photos.Select(c => c.ImageUri).FirstOrDefault()
        });
```

The problem with this is that for every user it creates a SELECT on Photos. I was looking for a solution that did not require an additional query on the database for every user record.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Comment: I understand but I have very much simplified what I require, so I can show a very simple example here. I am using EF Core (C#) and the domain is very different to the above. This is why I did not include what I have attempted as it does not relate to Users and Photos in such a simple way. Sorry. I have tried something like this: var users = _context.Users.Select(x => new {  name = x.Name,  photo = x.Photos.Select(c => c.ImageUri).FirstOrDefault() }); which results in multiple selects which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Your LINQ query is fine. How do you know it creates multiple queries? It shouldn't, and if it does, then the problem is in the EF Core (which is still unreleased, which version are you using - RC1, RC2  etc?)

Comment: I'm using EF .NET Core RC2. You can see the SELECTs in Visual Studio 2015 Output window. OK so maybe in final release it should be a single query similar to the SQL do you think?

Comment: Hmm, too bad, I think RC2 was supposed to be closer to RTM (w/o tooling), but who knows.

Comment: Posted to EF Core GitHub repository issues https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5754